# Javascript: How to get value of key in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to get one value of the first item in each object. My code works to get the objects but I can't figure out how to get the value that I want.

```
function getExcerpt() {
  var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://xxxxxxxx.org/wp-json/wp/v2/portfolio');
  ourRequest.onload = function () {
    if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
      var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
      
      for (i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i].excerpt)
      }
    } else {
      console.log("We connected to the server, but it returned an error.");
    }
  };
  ourRequest.onerror = function () {
    console.log("Connection error");
  };
  ourRequest.send();
}
getExcerpt()
```

This is what it being logged in the console. Now I just need to grab the value of rendered.

*{rendered: "This blog post from Smart Parent Advice lists six reasons you shouldn't yell at your kids", protected: false}*

Comment: `let o = data[i].excerpt; console.log(o.rendered); console.log(o.protected);`

Comment: Is `excerpt` a string or an object? Have you tried `data[i].excerpt.rendered`?

Comment: And to map them all `var renders = data.map(el=> el.excerpt.rendered)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
          var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
          let render =[];
          //Use this for block 
          for (i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data[i].excerpt);
            let temp = data[i].excerpt; 
            render.push(temp.rendered); 
          }
         //Or Use This
          render = data.map(ob => ob.excerpt.rendered);
}
```

Try this

Answer (score -1):

> I'm trying to get one value of the first item in each object

The `Object.values` function returns an array of an objects values. In your case we can just grab the first one (`[0]`).

```
let a = { test: 2, test2: 3};
Object.values(a)[0]
```

The above example outputs
`2`